# Please explain how Trial Division works for Primality Test

Tags: java, algorithm, primes

I came across this algorithm for testing primality through trial division I fully understand this algorithm

```
static boolean isPrime(int N) {
    if (N < 2)
        return false;
    for (int i = 2; i <= Math.sqrt(N); i++)
        if (N % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

It works just fine. But then I came across this other one which works just as good but I do not fully understand the logic behind it.

```
static boolean isPrime(int N) {
    if (N < 2)
        return false;
    for (int i = 2; i * i<N; i++)
        if (N % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

It seems like `i *i < N` behaves like `i <= Math.sqrt(N)`. If so, why?

Comment: `i <= sqrt(N)` <=> `i² <= N` because the function sqrt is stricly increasing on its domain's definition.

Comment: "If so, why?" Square both sides of the `i <= Math.sqrt(N)` equation.

Comment: `i *i < N` does ***not*** behave like `i <= Math.sqrt(N)`,  `i *i <= N` does.

Comment: Until you get to large numbers, where `i * i` can overflow and the floating-point result of `Math.sqrt(n)` might become inaccurate.  So beware.  Here it is OK, because both are limited by `n`.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, you can speed up your code with a few tweaks, if you think it is too slow:

```
static boolean isPrime(int N) {
    if (N <= 1)
        return false;
    if (N % 2 == 0)
        return N == 2;
    for (int i = 3; i <= Math.sqrt(N); i += 2)
        if (N % i == 0)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

This version does special tests for negatives and divisibility by 2 and then only divides by odd numbers from then on: 3, 5, 7, ... (note the  "+= 2").

Comment: imagine if N were 4, your proposed tweak will fail in testing

Comment: @mister_dani Whoops!  Thanks for the correction.  I have edited my code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are right, those are identical and obviously equation `i <= Math.sqrt(N)` can be rewritten for integers as `i * i <= N`, if you square both parts of first equation.
,
i.e. `a < b` is equiavalent to `a * a < b * b`, for positive a, b;

Comment: kiruwka thank so much for the help, I can't believe i missed that